# How to copy rows between worksheets based on a text value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy an entire row from one worksheet to another worksheet based on the occurrence of a specific text value ("Yes") in column H of the row.

I found this code and would like to change it to search through multiple sheets in the workbook. I've read about using an array, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

It doesn't need to examine the first 1000 rows if that needs to be changed, the whole sheet is fine.

Thank you.

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan 19")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Storage")

    J = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("H1:H1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c = "yes" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can you explain a bit more about searching through multiple Worksheets & then copying in which worksheet etc?

Comment: Hello, instead of just searching the sheet "Jan 19" for "Yes" and copying the row to the sheet "Storage" I'd like it to search through other sheets too "Feb 19" "Mar 19" and so on and copy all rows found to "Storage"

Answer (score 3):

I would just filter your range and then copy the filtered data like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyYes()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Col As Long, Lrow As Long
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet
    Dim arrws
    Dim HandleIt As Variant

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Storage")

    arrws = Array("Jan 19", "Feb 19") 'add all the worksheets you need to loop through

    For Each Source In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        HandleIt = Application.Match(Source.Name, arrws, 0)
        If Not IsError(HandleIt) Then
            With Source
                .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="yes"
                LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
                Col = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Lrow = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, Col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Target.Range("A" & Lrow)
            End With
        End If
    Next Source

End Sub
```

You will get the same output in just one go avoiding the loop.

Comment: OP wants it to loop through multiple worksheets in workbook.